# How can I check if string has particular word in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, contains

Now, I know I can calculate if a string contains particular substring.Using this:

```
if(str.indexOf("substr") > -1){
}
```

Having my substring 'GRE' I want to match for my autocomplete list:

> GRE:Math
>
> GRE-Math

But I don't want to match:

> CONGRES

and I particularly need to match:

`NON-WORD-CHAR`GRE`NON-WORD-CHAR`
and also 
`GRE`

What should be the perfect regex in my case?

Comment: FYI, added detailed explanation to the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to use `\b` word boundaries:

`(\bGRE\b)`

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary) is the explanation

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/hJ3vL6

Answer (score 2):

MD, if I understood your spec, this simple regex should work for you:

```
\W?GRE(?!\w)(?:\W\w+)?
```

But I would prefer something like `[:-]?GRE(?!\w)(?:[:-]\w+)?` if you are able to specify which non-word characters you are willing to allow (see explanation below).

This will match

```
GRE
GRE:Math
GRE-Math
```

but not `CONGRES`

Ideally though, I would like to replace the `\W` (non-word character) with a list of allowable characters, for instance `[-:]` Why? Because `\W` would match non-word characters you do not want, such as spaces and carriage returns. So what goes in that list is for you to decide.

How does this work?

`\W?` optionally matches one single non-word character as you specified. Then we match the literal `GRE`. Then the lookahead `(?!\w)` asserts that the next character cannot be a word character. Then, optionally, we match a non-word character (as per your spec) followed by any number of word characters.

Depending on where you see this appearing, you could add boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex: `/\bGRE\b/g`

```
if(/\bGRE\b/g.test("string")){
  // the string has GRE
}
else{
  // it doesn't have GRE
}
```

`\b` means word boundary